# Get value in a 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, 2d

I have this array:

```
$array = array (
    "key1" => "Value 1",
    "key2" => "Value 2",
    "key3" => "Value 3",
    "key4" => "Value 4",
    ...
);
```

I am submitting a key with a form, so I want to assign a variable the value that belongs to that key, for example:

```
$key = $_POST['key'];
$value = ?????; //this is what I need
```

This might be very simple, but I haven't done it in a very long time and I have forgotten how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: For reference: this isn't a 2D array.  It's just an associative array you index with a dynamic key.  PHP doesn't *technically* have 2D arrays, but a good-enough equivalent (in most cases) would be an array of arrays -- meaning in PHP's rendition of a 2D array, each of those values would itself be an array.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$value = $array[$key];
```

or without another variable:

```
$value = $array[$_POST['key']];
```

If you do receive a `Notice: Undefined index ...` you should check your array before you try to get the value with:

```
$value = array_key_exists($_POST['key'], $array) ? $array[$_POST['key']] : null;
```

This condition checks if the key exists. If so, it gets the value. If not, the value of `$value` will be `null`.

Comment: I am trying that, but even though it shows me the results I want, it's also showing this: Notice: Undefined index: $key, by the way I'm using PHP 5.5

Comment: @jfha73: Showing what?

Comment: check my previous comment, I just hit Enter by mistake, I just edited it.

Comment: @jfha73: That typically means you don't have a POST variable named 'key'.   You'll want to make sure `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` and/or `isset($_POST['key'])` are true before you use `$_POST['key']`.  Particularly if this code is in a script that handles both GET and POST requests.

Comment: But I do, if I add an echo $key it shows me what $_POST['key'] has as per my question shows "$key = $_POST['key']"

Comment: Yes but your array could not have this key. So you have to check via array_key_exists($_POST['key'], $array).

Comment: @jfha73: Then there are probably quoting issues.  Make sure you don't have `$key` in single quotes.  `$array['$key']` will not do what you want.

Comment: Got it, I replaced:

    $array['$key'];

for

    $array[$_POST['key']];

Even though they are the same and it worked.

Comment: No they are not. If you enclose an php variable in singlequotes it will be treated like a string.

Comment: Well, I just tried it using no quotes at all ($array[$key]) and it worked too, so thanks guys for taking your time and help me on this, but you can mark this as answered.

Comment: @jfha73: Marking it as answered is your job. Just click an the grey checkmark ;)